# Генерация букв на Java

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Как записать генерацию рандомных букв?

Comment: каких букв? русского или английского алфавита?

Answer (score 6):

Можно создать массив `char[]`, в котором будут храниться всевозможные символы, которые могут быть сгенерированы.

Далее, с помощью генератора псевдослучайных чисел получать некоторое псевдослучайное число из диапазона от нуля и до `char[].length - 1`.

А потом просто брать из массива `char[]` символ по полученному индексу.

```
public class Main {
    private static Random sRandom = new Random();
    private static char[] sAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    private static int sLength = sAlphabet.length;

    public static char getRandomChar() {
        return sAlphabet[sRandom.nextInt(sLength)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.println(getRandomChar());
        }
    }
}
```

Можно реализовать по-другому: генерировать число в диапазоне от минимального кода возможного символа до максимального, а потом просто кастовать `int` к `char`.

Answer (score 4):

Получение рандомных букв, без учета алфавита

```
private static char getRandom() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int codePoint;
    while (!Character.isAlphabetic(codePoint = random.nextInt(Short.MAX_VALUE * 2))) ;

    return (char) codePoint;
}
```